# How to Delete /Remove input values on backspace key

Tags: javascript, jquery, backspace

How do I delete/remove input values on backspace using javascript or jquery?
I entered several email ids in a textbox by separating them with comma, tab etc. On backspace key I want to delete the input values one by one.

Please give any function to implement this functionality.

---

Here is my front end code:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper topspacing-subsection leftspacing-subsection ">
    <div class="textarea wordcontainer" style="display:inline-block;width:690px;" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('txtSendFromType').focus();">
        <%--width 372 px removed from  txtSendFromType--%>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSendFromType" runat="server" CssClass="word" BorderStyle="None" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, hope it helps you:

```
var input = document.getElementById('txtSendFromType');
  input.onkeydown = function() {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
    return false;   
};
```

Comment: i tried this code but not working for me. but then also thanks for your help.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('keyup', 'input.word', function (e) {
                if ($('.word').val().length === this.size) {
                    var inputs = $('input.word');
                    inputs.remove();
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                    var inputs = $('input.word');
                    inputs.remove();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

Comment: i used this but it delete or remove current input value but if i click backspace twice 0r thrice it goes back